# Python - custom keyboard for Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm trying to write up a Telegram bot from scratch using Python and Flask, without existing libraries, for learning sake.

I'm still stuck with custom keyboard and its syntax. Can anyone show me the right method with a simple example? Starting from here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json, requests

keyboard = json.dumps({'inline_keyboard': [[ "<user1>", "<user2>" ]]})
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot-id>/sendMessage"
kbd = {'text':'Whatever','chat_id':'<channel>','reply_markup': keyboard}
send_kbd = requests.post(url,data=kbd,headers=headers)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope that´s of any help, I am sending you an example in PHP:```$customKeyboard = json_encode(['inline_keyboard' => [[['text' => "BUTTON 1", 'url' => "LINK 1"]], [['text' =>  "BUTTON 2", 'url' => "LINK 2"]]]]);
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$message."&parse_mode=Markdown&reply_markup=".$customKeyboard);``` I guess you already checked this [documentation](https://irazasyed.github.io/telegram-bot-sdk/usage/keyboards/) or the official  [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards) on this?

Comment: Yes I checked documentation but with no luck, I'll try your solution thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Telegram responses are well informative on the issues.

[InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) is an Array of Array of `InlineKeyboardButton` which any element of outer array defines a set of buttons in a row. `InlineKeyboardButton` by itself must be `json` object, requires a `text` key and also requires **exactly** one of `url`, `callback_data`, `switch_inline_query`, `switch_inline_query_current_chat`, `callback_game` set of keys. for more information [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton).

Change `keyboard` to:

```
keyboard = '{
   "inline_keyboard": [
       [
           {"text":"baa boo", "url":"http://some.url"},
           {"text":"boo baa", "switch_inline_query":""}
       ]
   ]
}'
```

and you may need to replace `<bot-id>` and `<channel>` to correct codes, if you did not.

Answer (score 0):

A correctly formatted (JSON) message with inline buttons looks like this:

```
{
  "text" : "Whatever text",
  "chat_id" : 0123456798,
  "reply_markup": {
    "inline_keyboard": [
       [
         {
           "text": "text",
           "callback_data": "click_data"
         }
       ],
       [
         {
           "text": "text",
           "callback_data": "click_data"
         }
       ]
     ]
   }
 }
```

Please note that a [inline button](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) must be an object.
You are not allowed to send text-only buttons by Telegram.

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work. I'm surely missing something else, but thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

hellow guys, i found a soloution in python, here it is:
first of all you need to send a text with it.

```
urlrequest='https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendmessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&text=<your text>'

keyboard={'keyboard':[[{'text':'text1'}],[{'text':'text2'}]]}

key=json.JSONEncoder().encode(keyboard)

url=urlrequest+'&reply_markup='+key

response=urlopen(url)
```

it worked for me, try it maybe worked for you.
thanks of your attention.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.